# Android studio Could not find kotlin-compiler.jar error on execute lint

Tags: android-studio, release, lint

I tested and debugged my app successfully but when I want to release apk of my app, on `Execute Lint` it got into this error :

```
Could not find kotlin-compiler.jar (com.android.tools.external.com-intellij:kotlin-compiler:26.5.0).
Searched in the following locations:
    https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/external/com-intellij/kotlin-compiler/26.5.0/kotlin-compiler-26.5.0.jar
```

when I click that link, it successfully get downloaded in browser, but I have no idea why android sutdio could not find it.
Also my offline work is unselected.

Comment: please check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51878497/java-android-apk-release-mode-error-could-not-download-kotlin-compiler-jar/51878650

Comment: offline work is currently unselected

Comment: did you find the solution? I got exactly the same error but non of the solutions in StackOverflow worked.

Answer (score 0):

I disabled offline work in gradle tab and also according to [answers of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46972122/could-not-find-com-android-tools-lintlint-gradle-android-studio-3) I changed order of repositories but none of those solved my problem.
Instead I cleared cache and after that everything came back to normal. Here is how I cleared gradle cache:

1. Clear Project Cache — there are 2 hidden directories in the main level of your project (after your first compile). Hint: on Mac type “cmd-shift-.” if you don’t see these files in your Finder window.
   Delete both the directories:

   [project home]/.idea

   [project home]/.gradle
2. Delete the system Gradle cache. Delete this folder:

   /[userhome]/.gradle/cache